# Puzzled in unit stuff .. please help

Tags: calculus

[image]Suppose that water is stored in a cylindrical tank of radius 5m. If the height of the water in the cylinder is h and we drain the water at the rate of 250 liter per minute. What is the rate at which the water level (h) inside the tank drops?

Comment: You may want to give a try to the exercise by yourself and then ask. Knowing the solution will no help you at all.
Take a look to some related rates problems and try to solve this one.

Comment: I gave it a try, image attached..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your volume $V = area*height = (5m)h$

you have $\frac{dV}{dt} = -250\frac{liter}{minute}$

and you know that a liter is $\frac1{1000}m^3$

You can substitute that back in to your derivative then solve the calculus equation for
$\frac{dH}{dt}$

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :) @kleineg

Answer (score 0):

Hint: to find the volume of a tank you multiply the height and surface area of - let's say - the bottom of the tank.

Comment: But its about the water level inside the tank

Comment: @user121237 It is not more than a hint in the sense of: start with finding out how much water there is in the tank if it is full (height $h$) and secondly find out the height after a minute.